# Routing via sub-interfaces not working?

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking

I'm trying to isolate outbound network traffic to a specific target for metering purposes, so I thought I'd route it via a dedicated IP address.  In order to achieve this I have setup a subinterface `eth0:1`, which appears as follows:

```
# ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast  state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether fa:16:3e:42:ae:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.111.6/24 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.111.5/24 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global secondary eth0:1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So far so good.  The routing piece that's supposed to make it work is this:

```
# ip route add 10.10.0.10 via 192.168.111.1 dev eth0:1
```

When I check the routing table, I get:

```
# ip route list
default via 192.168.111.1 dev eth0 
10.10.0.10 via 192.168.111.1 dev eth0 
192.168.111.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.111.6
```

Notice the 2nd line, which ends in `dev eth0` rather than `eth0:1` as I'd expect but so far this could just be a display issue.  However, when observing the traffic using `tcpdump`, it's obvious the route is behaving as the above display suggests, ie: traffic to `10.10.0.10` transits via the main interface `eth0`, using its IP `192.168.111.6` rather than `eth0:1's` IP `192.168.111.5`.

The weird thing is that if I use a dedicated NIC (eth1) rather than a subinterface as above, everything works as expected.  Is this a limitation of subinterfaces, a bug or am I doing smth wrong?

The OS is Ubuntu 14.04.3 server running on kernel 3.13.0-76.  It's a guest VM hosted on a KVM hypervisor (though I doubt this is a factor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want using this command:

```
ip route add 10.10.0.10 dev eth0:1 src 192.168.111.5
```

If you enter `ip route list` you should see the change of `src`.

Comment: Many thanks Oliver; the only thing I had to add was the next hop, as in:  `ip route add 10.10.0.10 via 192.168.111.1 dev eth0:1 src 192.168.111.5`; this works flawlessly.  Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, you don't even need "dev eth0:1".